# QPushButton icon maximize on resize event

Tags: qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

I have a question about resizing an icon on a QPushButton. Target system is Qt 4.8.6 on Linux. I am using QPushButton to create buttons with icons only, no text. I would like to have the icon as large as possible centered on the button including some margin.

I do not want the button size to adapt to the image size, I want the image size to adapt to the button size, while the button size adapts automaticly to the GUI size through QGridLayout or manually resizing.

When simply creating the button, the icon is only loaded small within the middle:

```
const QString fileName = "Bitmaps/btn.png";
if( !QFile( fileName ).exists() )
{
    qDebug() << "File not found: " << fileName;
}
const QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap( fileName );
m_btn = new QPushButton( QIcon( pixmap ), "", this );
```

When resizing through manual setting, the icon does not scale:

```
m_btn->setGeometry( QRect( 100, 100, 50, 50 ) );
```

To get the icon size rescaled I need to manually call setIconSize(). I can call this within the resize event of the instanciating widget.
But handling the margin still has to be calculated manually.

```
m_btn->setIconSize( QSize(  ( m_btn->size().width() - 12 ),
                            ( m_btn->size().height() - 12 ) ) );
```

But, as I get from the Qt Documentation there is a Stylesheet based layout thing called "The Box Model" which is applied to QPushButton as well.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model

So my question is, how do I configure the push button icon to fill the "content" area (marked as grey in the above document).
Possibly how do I configure it, that the icon resizes automaticly?
Your help is appreciated :-)

Comment: I ended up using the solution presented in my question. Within the parent resize event recalculate the new icon size manually.